# Ruptured wires or faulty circuit on a notebook keyboard?

Tags: computers

I have a notebook Acer Aspire V3-771G

Recently the following set of keys started to work only intermittently:

3,4,E,D,C

They either all work or none. At first I thought this was a problem with dirt and I had to clean my notebook keyboard, but since they all work or they all don't work, this might be a software problem? Or a single ciruit communicates with these five keys and a wire is partially ruptured or the circuit is faulty.

Anyone recognize the problem and know of a solution? I posted it here since it might be a circuit related problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern keyboards use [matrix scanning](http://www.openmusiclabs.com/learning/digital/input-matrix-scanning/). It is likely that all those keys are on the same column, and that column line has become damaged within the keyboard itself. Replace the keyboard.

Comment: I think the question is fair and appropriate for the site. IVA provided a good answer also